# Оторвался footer

Tags: html, css

Все было хорошо, но как только колличество товаров превешает 5-6 шт, то футер взлетает вверх. Я новичек в верстке. Уже час сижу и просто непонимаю как и почему. Может я плохо искал но ничего не нашел по этой проблеме.

http://www.xn--80aaabr8aazjnefi7k.xn--p1ai/pages/productsList?id=16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `product__photo` свойство `min-height` пределайте. Она у вас выпадает.